# How to 301 redirect urls with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I dont know how is the right way to redirect this:

```
RewriteRule ^set-(.*)-top-(.*)$ kat.php?st=$1&znamime=$2
RewriteRule ^set-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ kat.php?st=$1&sir=$2&vis=$3&pre=$4
RewriteRule ^set-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ kat.php?st=$1&ime=$2&col=$3
RewriteRule ^set-(.*)-(.*)$ kat.php?st=$1&ime=$2
RewriteRule ^set-(.*)$ kat.php?st=$1
```

This URLs look like this:

```
/set-cool-top-brand
/set-cool-25-8-12
/set-cool-big-19
/set-cool-small
/set-cool
```

The COOL is called in php. Now I will change it to BEST and I need help how   to 301 redirect it right for all options?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear.

Comment: The rewrite rules you posted do not have the string "cool" hard referenced in any way. So the rules should work likewise whether that words is replace with "best" or with anything else.

Comment: Yes it works with any word I choose...but I need redirect string "cool" to "best" because of search engines... maybe RedirectMatch will somehow help? or just redirect? but dont know how

Comment: OK, that makes it a bit more clear. Please add such additional information in the question itself, not jsut in comments. And add the "cool" to the matching pattern and fill in the "best" in the target of the rules.

Comment: Another thing: you write of "redirect" which your rules actually implement a "rewrite" and _not_ a "redirect". Which is it you want?

Comment: but it redirect it because now if I open urldomain.ltd/set-cool it goes to domain.ltd/set-best

Comment: That is impossible, your rule set does not even mention the word "best" currently.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^set-cool(.*)$ /set-best$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for, considering your additional comment to the question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?set-cool-top-(.*)$ kat.php?st=best&znamime=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?set-cool-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ kat.php?st=best&sir=$1&vis=$2&pre=$3 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?set-cool-(.*)-(.*)$ kat.php?st=best&ime=$1&col=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?set-cool-(.*)$ kat.php?st=best&ime=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?set-cool$ kat.php?st=best [END]
```

It matches the literal string "set-cool" and fills in the fixed and literal string "best" as "st" GET argument.